# Images are not fetchig from next js API and returning 500 error

Tags: laravel, next.js, fetch-api, server-side-rendering

Basically I want to fetch the data from the Laravel server to the NextJs API server and this seems to be working fine for the other attributes like the title but the image is not fetching and return error 500 and 'ECONNREFUSED'

[image: the error that appears in image]

Here is the code for courses inside the API colder `pages/api/courses.ts`

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import axios from "axios";

import Course from "../../models/course";

export default async function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
) {
  const courses = await Course.fetchAll();

  res.status(200).json(courses);
}
```

**Code for the API route on Laravel**

```
Route::get('/courses', function () {
    $courses = Courses::all();
    // allow remote access
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    return response()->json(['courses' => $courses], 200);
});
```

**Code for the API call**

```
const fetchCourses = async () => {
    const courses = await axios.get("http://localhost:3000/api/courses", {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        // allow cors
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      },
    });
    setCourses(courses.data);
};
```

**The image appears like that**

[image]

**The error that appears on the image URL**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by replacing the NextImage tag with normal image tag and it worked